# ASP.NET Core CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core

New to ASP.net Core

Where is the appropriate place to modify CSS to have the intended effect on the page?  I'm not sure the hierarchy here in how the CSS is read in the templates.

I've tried linking my own .css, modifying the wwwroot>>css>>site.css file, modifying the wwwroot>>lib>>bootstrap>>dist>>css>>bootstrap.css file, and using in-line styles.  The only one that works is in-line, and this is against our coding standards.

Edit:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - AppName</title>

    <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
    @Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript)
</head>
```

Comment: Can you please post a snippet of your `_Layout.cshtml` file? Specifically, the `<head>...</head>` section. In most cases, it points to `"~/css/site.min.css"`, which is a "minified" version of `site.css`. You need to ensure you re-minify after any changes to `site.css`, or make your Development environment use `site.css` instead of `site.min.css`

Comment: Changing <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" /> to <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" /> fixed it.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped! Dotnet Core was my first time developing with my own minified files, so I ran into the same issue as you on my first project. Just remember when you go to deploy to Staging or Production that you re-compile the minified files. I can't remember if it's part of the default deployment actions or not.